# How to randomly pick up specific number of items from an array using v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I want to randomly select the specific number of items from an array based on the user input. The array is like:

```
arr: [
   1.png, 2.png, 3.png, ..., 100.png
]
```

I have a method for shuffling the array when the user clicks the 'generate' button. However, I don't know how can I control the number of items using v-for. If I do

`<img v-for="n in arr" :key="n" :src="/static/images/${n}.png">`,

I will just get the entire array.

Comment: `v-for="n in arr.slice(0, howMany)"`

Comment: I know it's taboo to recommend outside libraries, but if you have Lodash in your project it's a simple as `_.sampleSize(arr, 5)` to pick 5 random elements from the array https://lodash.com/docs#sampleSize

Comment: Thank you,  very helpful. I should review some common functions of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage by using Vue.js, so you could define a `computed` property called `subArray` as follow :

```
       data(){
       return{
        ... 
       userInputValue:this.arr.length //by default get all the array, this property 
        }                              // is bound to input, it can be changed 
       }
      computed:{
         ...
         subArray(){
             return this.arr.splice(0,this.userInputValue);
          }
       }
```

in your template :

```
  <img v-for="n in subArray" :key="n" :src="/static/images/${n}.png">
```

**Note**: *don't put your logic inside template it's not a good practice, so keep it in your script*